Using Mlogit for my stated preference survey
I am a student writing is thesis, very unexperienced in R but I have to use it. My research is a stated preference survey based on a choice between a bike, or public transport commute. I have to use the mlogit funciton to fit a MNL, but I cant seem to figure it out.

mlogit_Employee <- dfidx(DFemployee, choice = "RES", varying = 4:26, shape = "long")
Error in guess(varying) :
failed to guess time-varying variables from their names

This is what I keep seeing
I have shaped my data in excel to a long format and have created dummies for each attribute. It doesn't look pretty, but figured it was the easiest. See the image for what that looks like. I have added it to R no problem. But am unsure where to go from here. Can someone assist me?
